# Including of files does not work as it should - url routing

Tags: php, nginx, routes, url-routing

My redirect process is showing some crazy stuff. The first part of the whole loop works just fine (if only the first element is typed in).

Possible url's look like:

> www.site.com/category
>
> www.site.com/category/product

But also:

> www.site.com/cart

Using site.com/jeans works just fine.  But when you click on a product, something strange happens.

The categorie.php file (used to display categories) is STILL included and after that one, the product.php file is included.

Same story with the cart page (http://www.site.com/winkelwagen/).

So my includes are wrong at some point. Winkelwagen is a folder on my site which has an index file. It should include http://www.site.com/winkelwagen/index.php and not categorie.php as well.

The route code :

```
<?php

$mult = Array();
if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ) ) {
$mult = explode ( '/', substr ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], 1 ) );
} else if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' ] ) ) {
$mult = explode ( '/', substr ( $_SERVER[ 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' ], 1 ) );   
} else if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'PATH_INFO' ] ) ) {
$mult = explode ( '/', substr ( $_SERVER[ 'PATH_INFO' ], 1 ) );
}

if(empty($mult[0]))
{
include("comingsoon/index.html");
}

if(!empty($mult[0]) && empty($mult[1]))
{
$file = "$mult[0].php";
if($mult[0] == "index2")
{
    include("index2.php");
    die;
}
// if file exists include file
if(file_exists($file))
{
    include($file);
}
else 
{
    $file2 = "/$mult[0]/index.php";

    // if folder index file exists include that file
    if(file_exists($file2))
    {
        include($file2);
    }   
    else {
        // if folder index file doesn't exist, send to category page
        $_GET['q'] = $mult[0];
        include("categorie.php");
    }
}
}
if(!empty($mult[0]) && !empty($mult[1]))
{
if($mult[0] == "add")
{
    $_GET['addid'] = $mult[1];
    include("addtocart.php");
}
elseif($mult[0] == "remove")                    
{
    $_GET['removeid'] = $mult[1];
    include("deletefromcart.php");
}
// check if folder exists (first part of the url)
elseif(is_dir($mult[0]))
{
    // check if file .php (second part of the url) exists
    $filenew = "$mult[0]/$mult[1].php";

    if(file_exists($filenew))
    {
        // include that file
        include("$mult[0]/$mult[1].php");
    }
    else 
    {
        // second file does not exist, do something
    }
}
else 
{
    // folder does not exist so redirect to product page
    $_GET['c'] = $mult[0];
    $_GET['p'] = $mult[1];
    include("product.php");
}
}
?>
```

I tried removing the categorie.php file but it still shows up (like, how on earth ?!)

I'm excited for the answer - I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Also nice to know: when I comment out the include(categorie.php) part in the route code, the file is STILL included...

Comment: Where does nginx come in here? Do you have some rewriting happening in the nginx configuration files?

Comment: My server configuration is nginx, but I guess I can remove that tag. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It looks like you should be able to trace this down pretty quickly by examing what `$mult[0]` contains

Comment: @ernie how would you go about that? echo `$mult[0]` on each page? Trying that.

Comment: I'd just add it in the block of code you have that determines whether you include categorie.php or not.  Maybe right before you build out `$file2`.  I suggest this since your code is determining that $file2 doesn't exist, and thus including categorie.php . . . so you should try and find out what $file2 is (which depends on $mult[0]).  I'll also point out your question title is completely misleading, as you're not doing any redirects here, nor does this involve nginx.

Comment: @ernie thanks for your suggestion. That code is already inside the if mult0 exists and mult1 is empty loop, so that should not run at all when I have a url with mult1 specified. 

The funny part is: when I echo `$file2` or add anything to that code, it won't show on the page itself. So maybe the error is not in the router file?

Comment: @Andre the site is currently not showing anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok... Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'll start by saying you are allowed to post links, trying to disrupt links by using "dot" actually feels **more like spam**, to me at least.

I'll continue by advising you to not go with your site and that code public. It has various *security vulnerabilities*, to which I am not going to go into detail. But, let's just say I'm curious why your user is called **d284h1** and why your site/home is on a mount point `/mnt/home/d284h1`...

Heed my words. You just posted your routing logic and your site on a **very** public site.

---

Regarding your code. I really hope that's SO destroying your indentation and not your actual source code.

You are missing some control logic. Some of them **might** have been leading to the file inclusions you were experiencing. I also noticed a possible bug, where you were testing and including a file from the **root directory**, instead of relatively to your site path.

***Update:*** Actually looking back at your original code, absolutely referencing the file `$file2 = "/$mult[0]/index.php";` was causing `categorie.php` to load. And not having proper control logic, was causing multiple inclusions to occur in the file.

---

Took the liberty of revising your code, mildly. The below code, should not continue to include any random files. *Unless included files themselves do it.*

```
$mult = array();
if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ) ) {
    $mult = explode ( '/', substr ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], 1 ) );
} else if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' ] ) ) {
    $mult = explode ( '/', substr ( $_SERVER[ 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' ], 1 ) );   
} else if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'PATH_INFO' ] ) ) {
    $mult = explode ( '/', substr ( $_SERVER[ 'PATH_INFO' ], 1 ) );
}

if (empty($mult[0])) {
    include("comingsoon/index.html");
    die; #missing
}
# no need to test for !empty($mult[0]), if it were empty, the above die would fire
if (empty($mult[1])) {
    $file = "$mult[0].php";
    if($mult[0] == "index2") {
        include("index2.php");
        die;
    }
    // if file exists include file
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include($file);
        die; # missing die
    } # no need for else, you just die'd

    # renamed $file2 to $file, don't use temporary variable names in global scope. It clutters your application
    $file = "$mult[0]/index.php";# are you sure you meant to include from the root level?
    // if folder index file exists include that file
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include($file);
        die;# missing die
    } # no need for else, you just die'd

    // if folder index file doesn't exist, send to category page
    $_GET['q'] = $mult[0];
    include("categorie.php");
    die;# missing die
}

# don't do succesive if/elseif on the same variable, use a switch!
switch($mult[0]) {
    case'add':
        $_GET['addid'] = $mult[1];
        include('addtocart.php');
        break;
    case'remove':
        $_GET['removeid'] = $mult[1];
        include('deletefromcart.php');
        break;
}
if (is_dir($mult[0])) {
    // check if file .php (second part of the url) exists
    $filenew = "$mult[0]/$mult[1].php";
    if(file_exists($filenew)) {
        // include that file
        include("$mult[0]/$mult[1].php");
        die; # missing die
    }
} else {
    // folder does not exist so redirect to product page
    $_GET['c'] = $mult[0];
    $_GET['p'] = $mult[1];
    include("product.php");
}
```

My updates are commented with `#` and this is in no way the final form it should look like. Take a look at [PSR1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) for a mild idea, on what [coding standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions#Examples) are. They are meant to help and make you more proficient in your quest for the ultimate code, despite initially feeling cumbersome.

Other things I'd continue on doing are:

1. swapping `!empty($var)` with `isset($var[0])`, if $var is a string
2. swapping `include($file);die;` with `return include $file;`, if you're in the main scope
3. swapping if/elseif blocks with [ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?:)

Actually regarding #3, here's an example:

```
$mult = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'][0])
        ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        : isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'][0])
            ? $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']
            : isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'][0])
                ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
                : false
        ;
$mult = $mult
        ? explode('/', substr($mult, 1))
        : array();
```

P.S. I did not fix the security issues you were having, as I believe the code you are using should not be used. Consider [using a framework](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) or at least [learning from one](http://symfony.com/). Routing is the corner stone of good [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you're on the right path, go one step beyond.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your amazing answer! I posted my site url to show a live example. Thanks for pointing out the security issues.

I tried using your code but it still has the same problem. [link](http://www.ragged.nl/jeans/g-star) My product file does not include categorie.php nor does my classes file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please test this also and send your feedback, I just re-structured the code (I made the conditions more strict using if elseif else)

```
<?php

$mult = Array();
if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ) ) {
$mult = explode ( '/', substr ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], 1 ) );
} else if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' ] ) ) {
$mult = explode ( '/', substr ( $_SERVER[ 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' ], 1 ) );   
} else if( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'PATH_INFO' ] ) ) {
$mult = explode ( '/', substr ( $_SERVER[ 'PATH_INFO' ], 1 ) );
}

if(empty($mult[0]))
{
  include("comingsoon/index.html");
}

elseif(!empty($mult[0]) && empty($mult[1]))
{
  $file = "$mult[0].php";
  if($mult[0] == "index2")
  {
      include("index2.php");
      die;
  }
  else{
    // if file exists include file
    if(file_exists($file))
    {
        include($file);
    }
    else 
    {
        $file2 = "/$mult[0]/index.php";

        // if folder index file exists include that file
        if(file_exists($file2))
        {
            include($file2);
        }   
        else {
            // if folder index file doesn't exist, send to category page
            $_GET['q'] = $mult[0];
            include("categorie.php");
        }
    }
  }
}
elseif(!empty($mult[0]) && !empty($mult[1]))
{
  if($mult[0] == "add")
  {
      $_GET['addid'] = $mult[1];
      include("addtocart.php");
  }
  elseif($mult[0] == "remove")                    
  {
      $_GET['removeid'] = $mult[1];
      include("deletefromcart.php");
  }
  // check if folder exists (first part of the url)
  elseif(is_dir($mult[0]))
  {
      // check if file .php (second part of the url) exists
      $filenew = "$mult[0]/$mult[1].php";

      if(file_exists($filenew))
      {
          // include that file
          include("$mult[0]/$mult[1].php");
      }
      else 
      {
          // second file does not exist, do something
      }
  }
  else 
  {
      // folder does not exist so redirect to product page
      $_GET['c'] = $mult[0];
      $_GET['p'] = $mult[1];
      include("product.php");
  }
}
?>
```